# AWS: Cannot deploy Lambda to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda NET6, I deploy it from VS 2022 - it deployed OK.
But when I am trying to deploy it using command:

> dotnet lambda deploy-serverless -sn pm2stack -sb pm2bucket --region eu-west-2 -t serverless.template --profile default

it built, zipped but then gives me an error:

```
Uploading to S3. (Bucket: pm2dicts_bucket Key: AspNetCoreFunction-CodeUri-Or-ImageUri-638283878431414423-638283878579128476.zip)
Error uploading to AspNetCoreFunction-CodeUri-Or-ImageUri-638283878431414423-638283878579128476.zip in bucket pm2dicts_bucket: The specified bucket does not exist
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `eu-east-1` is not a valid [AWS region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.html).

Comment: Edited: eu-west-2, but an error is the same

Comment: Just confirming : Do you have all the necessary permissions to list the zip file to s3?

Comment: Part of your logs: `Bucket: pm2dicts_bucket ...`. Here `_` is not acceptable character for bucket name. Your example command parameter is `-sb pm2bucket`. The bucket name is different in command and logs. Or if `pm2dicts_bucket` is set somewhere else, it is not correct and should be fixed

Comment: Changed to pm2bucket and run again the command, now: error uploading to **** The specified bucket does not exist.  Should I create this bucket manually before running the command?

Comment: The bucket must exist in advance. Deployment of a Lambda function doesn't create that bucket.